# Radio button not changing background color HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I'm trying to change the background color using radio buttons. The javascript function seems to not be working. I already read through the other questions written here, none of those answers seemed to work.

Here's the HTML code:

```
 <form action="">

    <input type="radio" name="color" value="radio"  onchange= "bgColor('colorR')">Red
    <input type="radio" name="color"  value="radio" onchange= "bgColor('colorG')"> Green
    <input type="radio" name="color"  value="radio" onchange= "bgColor('colorP')"> Purple
    <input type="radio" name="color"  value="radio" onchange= "bgColor('colorD')"> Default

</form>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
 <script>

  function bgColor(col){

switch(col){

    case 'colorR':
        document.body.style.backgroundColor  = "red";
        break;

    case 'colorG':
         document.body.style.backgroundColor  = "green";
         break;

    case 'colorP'
          document.body.style.backgroundColor  = "purple";
          break;

    case 'colorD'
          document.body.style.backgroundColor  = "#d0e4fe";
          break;


     }
 }

 </script>
```

Here's the CSS code for when the page first launches:

```
 body {
     background-color: #d0e4fe;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('input:radio').click(function() {
  var color = $(this).val();
  $('body').css("background-color", color);

});
```

```css
 body {
   background-color: #d0e4fe;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">

  <input type="radio" name="color" value="red">Red
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="green">Green
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="purple">Purple
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="#d0e4fe">Default

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked!! Can you explain why? Is there a way to do it without jquery?

Comment: yes you can always do it with pure javascript if you want it in javascript i will post a fiddle.

Comment: Ya that would be great. I'm trying to figure out what I was missing.

Comment: the fiddle was useful, got it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because your function name is `bgColor` i have renamed it to `bgcolor` and you also missing semi-colon after `case 'colorP'` and `case 'colorD'` and now its working fine.
Try this

```
 <form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="radio"  onchange= "bgcolor('colorR')"> Red
  <input type="radio" name="color"  value="radio" onchange= "bgcolor('colorG')"> Green
  <input type="radio" name="color"  value="radio" onchange= "bgcolor('colorP')"> Purple
  <input type="radio" name="color"  value="radio" onchange= "bgcolor('colorD')"> Default
</form>
```

JavaScript function

```
 <script>
  function bgcolor(col){
    switch(col){
      case 'colorR':
        document.body.style.backgroundColor  = "red";
        break;
      case 'colorG':
        document.body.style.backgroundColor  = "green";
        break;
      case 'colorP' :
        document.body.style.backgroundColor  = "purple";
        break;
      case 'colorD':
        document.body.style.backgroundColor  = "#d0e4fe";
        break;
    }
 };
</script>
```

and css

```
 body {
   background-color: #d0e4fe;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. I'm new to Javascript, didn't realize methods need to be all lowercase.

Comment: @user3397546 In JavaScript methods need not to be all lowercase. but in this case i don't know why bgColor is not working.Will look into it.